# Redirecting a Flask route to an external URL

Tags: flask, redirect

I have the following route, which is supposed to redirect the user to an external URL (I'm using Apple's URL as an example here) -

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response, render_template
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId, json_util
import json

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.mpjcg.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["simply_recipe"]
collection = db["recipes_collection"]

app = Flask(__name__)

# This route returns the team's index page
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

# This route returns heesung's plot page of the team's website
@app.route("/heesung")
def heesung():
    return redirect("http://www.apple.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Issue:**
I keep getting a `"GET /heesung/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -` in my terminal, when I navigate to my `localhost/heesung`

**Note:**
I am aware there are other questions of similar nature and for those, I have followed the steps, but they are old posts, so I'm wondering if Flask has changed anything. I couldn't find any definitive documentation.

Comment: Are you forgetting the PORT? http://localhost:port/heesung

Answer (score 1):

As per V25's comment, I forgot to import the dependency. Sorry for everyone's trouble!

**Answer:**

```
from flask import redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to the `return redirect("http://www.apple.com")` line.

> I keep getting a `GET /heesung/ HTTP/1.1" 404` - in my terminal, when I navigate to my localhost/heesung

That terminal output suggests you're hitting `/heesung/` (with the trailing slash).

With the decorator:

```
@app.route("/heesung")
```

- Requests to `/heesung` will succeed
- Requests to `/heesung/` will 404.

Instead with the decorator:

```
@app.route("/heesung/")
```

- Requests to `/heesung/` will succeed
- Requests to `/heesung` will issue a '308 permanent redirect' to `/heesung/`

Pick whichever best suits your use-case.

Comment: OP said he navigated to the URL without the trailing slash.  Flask will append the trailing slash if the first try (without slash) fails.

Comment: @GAEfan OP said that, but the terminal output `GET /heesung/ HTTP/1.1" 404` suggests that the trailing slash *was* in the request.  I have tested this will Flask `1.1.1` and that server output will mimic what was in the request.  I suspect OP overlooked this, when stating the URL he requested.

Comment: Thanks for the comments thus far. When I use '@app.route("/heesung/")' I get a 500 error but ALSO a 'NameError: name 'redirect' is not defined'

Comment: @William need to do `from flask import redirect` at the top ;)